# Unable to build iOS app with Tesseract

Tags: xcode, cocoapods, tesseract

I am trying to read text from Image and I have used `pod 'TesseractOCRiOS', '4.0.0'` this library when I run this app in Simulator its working fine but in real device I got compile time error:

> ld: -weak_library and -bitcode_bundle (Xcode setting ENABLE_BITCODE=YES) cannot be used together
>
> clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

I have also change `ENABLE_BITCODE=False` but problem is not resolved 
I am following this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DTQ1z_8KXZo&t=286s

If you have any other idea for doing this please share with me

Comment: Did you do a clean before rebuilding?

Comment: yes i have tried all scenario like uninstall close and open Xcode ..

Comment: Try disabling bitcode for all the targets under Pods project also

Comment: Really you uninstalled XCode? Seems a bit extreme. For BITCODE to work, all code (including the libraries you use) need to be compiled with BITCODE enabled. So if this error pops up, it generally means that one or more libs are not compiled with that setting enabled.  So you will need to set ENABLE_BITCODE=NO/FALSE _for all projects in your workspace_, then clearn your build (cmd-shift-k) and rebuild it.

Comment: No i am not unistall Xcode , i have unistall simulator app .

Comment: @JigneshPatel after disable POD bitcode i am getting facebook Bolt error

Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Bolts/Bolts.framework/Bolts' does not contain bitcode. You must rebuild it with bitcode enabled (Xcode setting ENABLE_BITCODE), obtain an updated library from the vendor, or disable bitcode for this target. file '/Users/shamshersingh/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MicroShiner-hegwfkeppgpauegptpvvfgqhlntc/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Bolts/Bolts.framework/Bolts' for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: You can select FB Target under pod and keep it as enabled. You can select different target under pods and set a different setting for all SDK added using pods.